# VS 2015 Modeling Project MSB3268 warnings when using Unity IoC Container

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, unity-container

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 and tried to create a layer diagram in order to generate and validate dependencies. But this fails because VS is throwing warnings while building the modeling project:

> CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference
>   "...\ClassLibrary4\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary4.dll" could not be resolved
>   because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly
>   "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the
>   currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve
>   this problem, either remove the reference
>   "...\ClassLibrary4\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary4.dll" or retarget your
>   application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

I figured out that if you remove Unity the warnings are gone and dependencies are shown as expected.

**What is the reason for this behavior and is there any workaround?**

I tried the Unity prerelease package and also another targeting frameworks. No effect at all. The issue is reproducable with a new project after adding a modelling project and using unity in one referenced projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution after setting build output to detailed. The problem that VS2015 was compiling the modelling project using the wrong target framework (4.0):

> Task Parameter:TargetFrameworkDirectories=C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0

There is no TargetFrameworkVersion in the project file of the modelling project (*.modelproj). But after adding it to the first property group it is compiling and validading as expected. Without any warnings.

Solution:

1. Unload the modelling project
2. Right Click -> Open *.modelproj
3. Add the following line to the first Property (replace with your target framework)

(replace v4.5 with your target framework)

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Get happy using architecture tools.